# What's wrong with my simple CSS

Tags: css

I put the following at the beginning of my html, and it doesn't work. The point should be obvious, to set top and bottom margins to 25px and left and right to 75px. and also to indent the paragraphs. But nothing works, no matter what I do it doesn't even look like it's trying to run the code.

```
<style>
  <!--
    p {text-indent:10px;}
    margin:25px 75px;
  -->
</style>
```

Comment: `margin:25px 75px;` is invalid where it is, every property has to belong to a selector.

Comment: Get a reasonable IDE and it will highlight this sort of mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<style>

    p {
        text-indent:10px;
        margin:25px 75px;
    }

</style>
```

Then ensure you have a `<p>` tag in your HTML to apply this to.

I would focus on completing some basic HTML/CSS tutorials before pushing on much further :)

Comment: Thanks! I did just start on the tutorials :P

Answer (score 1):

The `<style>` should be inside `<head>` and it should look like this:

```
<head>
  <style>
    p {
      text-indent: 10px;
      margin: 25px 75px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the head tag :P Sorry for such a stupid question, I just started with this.